# change a session value before ending the session

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

The title might seem confusing but what Im trying to do is count the number of users actively on a page, what I thought of was :

sender.php

```
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['foo'])) {
    $_SESSION['foo'] = (string)((int) $_SESSION['foo'] + 1 ) ;
}else $_SESSION['foo'] = '1';
```

receiver.php

```
session_start();
$_POST['foo'] = $_SESSION['foo'];
$var = $_POST['foo'];
echo '<p style="font-size:80px">'.$var.'</p>';
```

the thing I'm still missing is how to decrease the number when closing the sender window.

Comment: `_SESSION` is unique for each user, so not sure how this would work - each user's count would be 1 until they left, then would go to 0...

Comment: the result I want to get in the end is : if sender.php is opened 'x' times the value on $var should be 'x', and whenever one of the sender.php is closed the number should decrease

Comment: Do you have a polling js script or something?  If not, there's really no way for PHP to know that the browser window has been closed.